# What is Darling's actual name in the show?

Tags: blackadder

In Season 4 of the British sitcom Blackadder, is the officer's name actually "Darling" or is it just a nick name?

If "Darling" is just a nick name, what is his real name in the show?

Answer (score 9):

The character's real name is [Kevin Darling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darling_%28Blackadder%29)

Its meant to just be a joke that his real name is also a term of endearment, setting up some good lines from the others, not that it is a nickname.  To a British ear, Darling sounds convincingly like it could be a last name of someone from the upper classes - like an officer in the British Army at the time.

Its worth pointing out that Darling is definitely more likely a last name than Blackadder itself. For example Darling was the last name of the family in Peter Pan, a story from the same era.